# My firebase google authentication stopped working suddenly and gives me this error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I implemented google auth in my firebase project using the signInWithRedirect method and it has been working normally until today and i can't see where the issue is coming from suddenly

this is my code

```
 const googleBtn = document.querySelector('#googleSignup')

  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  };

  getRedirectResult(auth)
    .then((result) => {
      const user = result.user;
      console.log('Successfully signed in with Google:', user);

      window.location.href = '/dist/pages/food_options.html';
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error signing in with Google:', error.message);
    });

  googleBtn.addEventListener('click', signInWithGoogle);
```

and here is the full error it's giving me:

> index.js:74  Error signing in with Google: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')